# Possible to add spacing every 4 characters in vi?

Tags: vi

Is it possible to add spacing every 4 characters in vi? And if it is, what's a good google term to search for to learn how to do similar stuff?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To add a space every 4 characters you could use the following command (at least in VIM):

```
:%s/\(....\)/\1 /g
```

If you Google "VIM Substitution" you should end up with some useful examples.

Example:

```
To add a space every 4 characters you could use
```

becomes

```
To a dd a  spa ce e very  4 c hara cter s yo u co uld  use
```

Comment: And to add one blank space after 14 characters in each line?

Comment: @HenioJR `:%s/\(.\{14\}\)/\1 /g` See more [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65739267/1498178).