# VIM command to insert spaces in after few characters?

Tags: vim

gvim command to insert a space or character after every few characters in a
file

example:
How to add space after every 12 characters in the below lines?

Before adding spaces:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrst
dkdkefghijklmnopqrst
```

After adding spaces

```
abcdefghijkl mnopqrstvgah
dkdkefghijkl mnopqrstbgdh
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Insert a character after (n) characters and repeat(n) times - vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16241250/insert-a-character-after-n-characters-and-repeatn-times-vim)

Answer (score 0):

You can jump to the 12th column by typing 12| so:

```
:%norm! 12|a<space>
```

Where space is typed literally

Comment: Hi, Thanks for reply. I need a command to insert space after every x letters in a line                                                                                                            
For examle:
Question:                                                                                                            
abcdefghsvijahnshiajmnsdf
achebgrthijafhetvdgrhjkhfgdrethsrthahb

Answer:
abcdefghsvij ahnshiajmnsd f
achebgrthij afhetvdgrhjk hfgdrethsrth ahb

Answer (score 0):

A generalized version of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4847888/1498178) fits here perfectly:

```
:'<,'>s/\(.\{12\}\)/\1 /g
             ^
             |
       substitute this with the number of characters
       after you'd like to insert spaces in
```

To break it down:

- `'<,'>` is the range; see `:h range`
- `s` is short for substitute; see `:h :s`
- `\(` and `\)` is [a regular expression (regex) capturing group](https://javascript.info/regexp-groups) ([`:help \(`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/%5C%28) is not very helpful...)
- `.` will match any single character
- `\{` and `\}` is a [regex match quantifier](https://javascript.info/regexp-quantifiers) meaning how many times a preceding pattern should be matched (`.\{3\}` means `...`, and so on)
- `\1` is pasting the text captured by the `\(`-`\)` block
- space
- `/g` is to replace all occurences of a pattern in a line (see `:h s_flags`)